# Store matrix from a loop in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix

I have a 5 by 3 matrix, e.g the following:

```
A=[1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 3; 4 4 4; 5 5 5]
```

I run a for loop:

```
for i = 1:5
    AA = A(i)'*A(i);
end
```

My question is how to store each of the 5 (3 by 3) `AA` matrices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pre-allocate enough memory to the **AA** matrix to hold all the results:

```
[r,c] = size(A);   % get the rows and columns of A (r and c respectively)
AA = zeros(c,c,r); % pre-allocate memory to AA for all 5 products 
                   % (so we have 5 3x3 arrays)
```

Now do almost the same loop as above BUT realize that **A(i)** in the above code only returns one element whereas you want the full row.  So you want the data from row **i** but all columns which can be represented as **1:3** or just the colon **:**

```
for i=1:r
    AA(:,:,i) = A(i,:)' * A(i,:);
end
```

In the above, **A(i,:)** is the ith row of **A** and we are setting all rows and columns in the third dimension (**i**) of **AA** to the result of the product.

Comment: Thank you Geoff. I didn't know how to operate in the third dimension. That really solved the problem. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, as in [Geoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23448991/2586922), that you mean `A(i,:)'*A(i,:)` (to get 5 matrices of size 3x3 in your example), you can do it in one line with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/permute.html):

```
AA = bsxfun(@times, permute(A, [3 2 1]), permute(A, [2 3 1]));
```

(I'm also assuming that your matrices only contain real numbers, as in your example. If by `'` you really mean *conjugate* transpose, you need to add a `conj` in the above).

Comment: Thank you Luis. Your answer did the job as well.